# How Do I install MegaFuse from Github? On Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu

I am trying to **install** an application or software on **Ubuntu** Machine hosted on a Droplet at DigitalOcean.

The application is hosted on **Github**. Called **MegaFuse** .

I have read the Info on the github site download the **repository** from https://github.com/matteoserva/MegaFuse.git via Wget command on my Ubunut machine.
I have **unpacked** the zip file using  unzip  then I try 
 **make ./Megafuse**

I get the following output.

```
make: pkg-config: Command not found 
g++ -I inc -I /usr/include/cryptopp -I sdk -std=c++0x -O0 -g -fstack-protector-all -Wall   -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG  -c src/MegaFuseApp.cpp -o src/MegaFuseApp.o
make: g++: Command not found
Makefile:43: recipe for target 'src/MegaFuseApp.o' failed
make: *** [src/MegaFuseApp.o] Error 127
```

I also installed the following application as described on github page it is required to compile the software.

```
apt-get install libcrypto++-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libfreeimage-dev libreadline-dev libfuse-dev
```

I **don't know** what to do now, Do you have any suggestions or perhaps you have some idea about *how I could Install this application?*

Answer (score 1):

The response indicates that you are missing the `g++` command.

You can install `g++` with:
`sudo apt-install g++`